# How do I dual-booting Ubuntu on a Macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, dual-boot

How would you dual-boot Ubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook Pro with the following specs: 13", 750GB hard drive, Intel Core-i7 processor, with 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rEFIt is the best way to allow dual-booting on a Mac. I use it to boot Ubuntu from a partition on my external drive, and it works perfectly. Be sure to back up your hard drive before proceeding.

> Install rEFIt and make sure it is working (you should get a boot
>   chooser on startup) Use Bootcamp or Disk Utility to create a partition
>   at the end of the disc. Don’t worry about what format, just make it
>   the size you want for Ubuntu and your swap partition. If you you are
>   using OS X Lion which comes with Bootcamp 4.0 you will need to use the
>   Disk Utility. Boot Camp 4.0 will only allow you to resize if you
>   provide a Windows 7 installation disk. Boot the Ubuntu desktop CD, and
>   select "Try Ubuntu. Start the partition editor (gparted) under System
>   -> Adminstration. Use gparted to delete the partition you just made in OS X. It should be the last partition on the disc and follows after
>   the HFS+ partition (OS X). Deleting it will leave an area called
>   unallocated. This is free space, and exactly what you want. Use
>   gparted to manually partition the space on your drive for Ubuntu.
>   First create a SWAP area of about 1GB. Then the rest of the
>   unallocated area format as EXT4. Apply changes and take note the label
>   of the EXT4 partition such as /dev/sda3.
>
> Start the Ubuntu Installer from the desktop icon. When prompted,
>   choose to manually partition. Select the EXT4 partition and click
>   change. Select to use the space as EXT4 and root (/) as the mount
>   point. You will also want to check the box to format the partition. 
>   Reboot when done with the install, and in the rEFIt menu, choose the
>   partition tool. It will attempt to sync the partition tables on your
>   disk. Then SHUTDOWN the computer (not reboot), and start it again. You
>   should be able to boot to Ubuntu now. If it seems to freeze on the tux
>   logo, completely shutdown again and try one more time.

This is a summary of a process described by the detailed how-to process here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Detailed_How-To

Comment: no problem; if this worked for you, you can mark my solution as accepted by pressing the check button next to my answer

Comment: sorry took me a while to figure that out, anyways is 128gb enough for macbook air dual boot with ubuntu?

Comment: Depends on how much space you wish to reserve for Ubuntu. You can create its partition to whatever size you'd like

Comment: This answer is a bit dated as *rEFIt* is not maintained anymore (and wouldn't directly work on recent Macs).